# FullCalendar month view events without resizing the cell size of calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

FullCalendar Week view has differnt way of displaying events rather than month view events. The overlaping events are shown without resizing the cell size of calendar. Is their any way to apply this to month view events?

I want to show my events without resizing the cell size of calendar in month view.Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some code or put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: ??? Please expand your question and add some code.

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar v2.1.0-beta2 introduces an `eventLimit` option that resolves this for month view.

See https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v2.1.0-beta2 for rough documentation on the new options introduced by addressing this issue: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=304 (as SaschaM78 noted before).

I've prepared a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/wijgerden/nv4qkLgt/ that has example events as shown in the original screenshot. Plus some extra events on 5/6 Feb 2014 to show the effect of `eventLimit: 5`: the 5 events `m1`...`m5` are all visible at once, while the 6 events named `n1`...`n6` are only partially shown. They are all revealed when you click on the "+2 more" link. In this case they are all-day events, but this also works for timed events and combinations of all-day and timed events.